# How to embed form data in the action link?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I have a form defined:

```html
<form method="post">
  <label for="phone_or_uid">Enter a phone number or uid:</label>
  <input type="text" name="phone_or_uid" value=""></input>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

Currently, when this form is submitted I am able to work with the data and add info to the page based on the value of `phone_or_uid`. However, what I'd like to do is something where the form redirects to the same page but with the value of `phone_or_uid` appended to the end. So, if the initial page is `https://myhost.com/lookup` then submitting the form should bring the user to `https://myhost.com/lookup/16175431234` if the value of the `phone_or_uid` input box is `16175431234`.

Essentially, my form should then look something like this:

```html
<form action={some code that puts the value of phone_or_uid here}>
  ...
</form>
```

Is this possible? And if so, how could I accomplish this? I don't want to create or redirect to any extra files, if possible.

Comment: [Form data mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

I would use JavaScript. Listen for the submit event and redirect to a custom url.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I might do this, or a resource where I can learn? I am almost completely unfamiliar with JS.

Answer (score 0):

this is just a really general example:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="submitFunction()">
    <label for="phone_or_uid">Enter a phone number or uid:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone_or_uid" id="phone_or_uid" value=""></input>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit"></input>
</form>

<script> 
    submitFunction = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const phoneInfo = document.getElementById('phone_or_uid').value;
        fetch('http://myhost.com/lookup/' + phoneInfo, {
            method: 'post'
        })
        .then(response => {
            window.location.href = "http://myhost.com/lookup/' + phoneInfo";
        });
    }
</script>
```